# Accept custom input for batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm using DOS batch scripting.

Is there a method for accepting input from a user that can be a custom range of integers, such as 1-250?

I want to accept a range of workstation names from a user, like 1-250, where each number within the range can be looped through, and sent to a different command depending on the number.

Workstation names could be in the number format of 3 possiblities: w0001, w0010, or w0100. So if I entered 1-250, it could be any one of those 3 formats: 3 leading zeros for a single digit, 2 leading zeros for double digit, or 1 leading zeros for triple digits.

Something Like this, using the SC query command just as an example:

```
set "range="

set /p range="Please enter workstation range:"

DO(if %range% > 0)

(

IF %range% = 1 
DO SC \\W000%range% query

IF %range% = 10
DO SC \\W00%range% query

IF %range% = 100
DO SC \\W0%range% query

)
```

I was looking into FOR /L or FOR /F but they only seem to be able to accept something like (1,1,10) or (filename.txt).in the "set" field. I need a user to be able to enter something simple like 1-250.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me what you are asking.

To iterate a range outputting a number with four places try this:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "range="
set /p range="Please enter workstation range:"
set "start="
set "stop="
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%A in ("%range%") do Set /A "start=%%A+10000,stop=%%B+10000"
if defined stop if %start% leq %stop% for /l %%L in (%start%,1,%stop%) do (
    set "L=%%L"
    Echo Processing \\w!L:~-4!
    Rem do whatever you like with the value 
)
```

Sample run:

```
> SO_46410755.cmd
Please enter workstation range:1-120
Processing \\w0001
Processing \\w0002
Processing \\w0003
Processing \\w0004
Processing \\w0005
Processing \\w0006
Processing \\w0007
Processing \\w0008
Processing \\w0009
Processing \\w0010
Processing \\w0011
Processing \\w0012
...
Processing \\w0096
Processing \\w0097
Processing \\w0098
Processing \\w0099
Processing \\w0100
Processing \\w0101
Processing \\w0102
...
Processing \\w0117
Processing \\w0118
Processing \\w0119
Processing \\w0120
```

- The first `for /f` splits the var `range` content at the minus/hyphen into two parts and stores the 1st into `start` adding 10000 and the 2nd into `stop` also adding 10000.
- `for /l` iterates the range from start (with step 1) to stop.
- to use [substrings](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) we need a normal variable so the for variable `%%L`is stored in the variable `L`
- as this happens in a (code block in parentheses) we need [delayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I don't understand is why you put +10000 after each variable in the FOR command. And in the ECHO output I don't understand the meaning of the characters ! : ~ -4.

Comment: To have leading zeroes when taking the last 4 chars and have a unique length when comparing

Comment: I need to have a single digit lead with three 0's, double digit with two 0's, and triple digit with one 0. So if I entered 1-120 as the input, it should output like this: w0001, w0002......w0050, w0051......w0100, w0120 etc. Also, could you explain  !L:~-4! or reference an article? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I don' understand. Edit your question to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, my previous post was cut off. Please see the last one.

Comment: But that **IS** exactly what the batch does. Changed the sample output. Simply try it. See help on [substrings](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Comment: Ok, its starting to make sense. For some reason I had to change the -4 to -5. I was getting results like: w001, w010, and w100 before I did. Now they are correct: w0001, w0010, and w0100. Do you know why? Couple of questions I still have. Why do you need "if defined stop", and are you using ! instead of % in the "echo Processing" substring? The tutorial doesn't show any use of !, only %.

Comment: Presumably there was a trailing space in the command `set L=%%L` I now enclosed the pair in double quotes to solve this.

Comment: Why do you need "if defined stop" and why use ! in the echo line? The tutorial shows using % with substrings.

Comment: It's an input validation, to ashure stop **has** a value. If not the second if will fail with a syntax error. BTW if you find an answer usefull you should vote up and/or accept the answer.

Comment: Why do you use the ! in the echo line? Looking at the tutorial for substrings, I don't see any mention of it.

Comment: You keep asking for additional information already provided in my (extended) answer without honouring my effort.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I have tried to vote your solutions more than once. I'm not sure if it's working. I also can't see where you explain the ! in the echo line. I have looked through the substring article but not seen any reference to it.

Comment: I'm trying to add error code to this batch file. After a user is prompted for, and enters a building number into %building%, the value is compared to an array of 6 set LANbuilding[1]=20, etc. I'm trying: if %building% neq !LANbuilding[%%n]! for /l %%n in (1,1,6) do ( echo invalid building, try again. For some reason the comparison is not working. I've echo'ed the values of %building% and !LANbuilding[%%n]! and they are holding the correct values, but I get the invalid building message no matter what I enter. Do you see what's wrong?

Comment: This is a new question and should be asked as that. Wrong order the iterating for has to be first. THE Var `%%n` is only valid in the scope of the for command.

Comment: Ok, so I'm trying the following, but it just closes the window.


`set "building="

set LANbuilding[1]=20
set LANbuilding[2]=21
set LANbuilding[3]=22
set LANbuilding[4]=23
set LANbuilding[5]=24
set LANbuilding[6]=25

:start

set /p building="Enter the building:> "

for /l %%n in (1,1,6) do ( if %building% neq !LANbuilding[%%n]!
echo invalid building, try again.

goto :start

)

else`


The else would be to continue with the rest of the code.